# Finding $\sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{N-j}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

How can we tackle $$\sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{N-j}$$ when $0<m<n<N$. I have been using Euler-Maclaurin sum to change this object to some integral but it gets a bit messy. I appreciate any hint!

Comment: $$\sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{N-j} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}a^{k}e^{(k+m-N)x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{(m-N)x}\frac{(ae^x)^{n-m+1}-1}{ae^x-1}\,dx$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio many thanks that looks good to me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may recall the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) function,
$$
\Phi(z, s, \alpha) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac { z^n} {(n+\alpha)^s}, \tag1
$$ which has been extensively studied by [Mathias Lerch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathias_Lerch) (1903) and which 
admits a standard integral representation:

> $$
> \Phi(z,s,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty
> \frac{t^{s-1}e^{-\alpha t}}{1-ze^{-t}}\,dt, \quad \Re(\alpha)>0\wedge\Re(s)<0\wedge z<1, \tag2
> $$

and, for $\Re z < \frac12$, may be represented by the series

> $$
> \Phi(z,s,q)=\frac{1}{1-z} 
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-z}{1-z} \right)^n
> \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (q+k)^{-s}. \tag3
> $$

Then, the given sum may be written as
$$
\sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{N-j}=\sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{(N-m)-(j-m)}=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{a^k}{k-(N-m)}
$$ leading to

> $$
> \sum_{j=m}^{n}\frac{a^{j-m}}{N-j}=a^{n+1 - m} \Phi(a, 1, n+1 - N)-\Phi(a, 1, m - N) \tag4
> $$

with appropriate restrictions for the given arguments. The preceding identity will allow some asymptotic expansions, as one may see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Series_representations).

Comment: I am happy with this development :-) though in my application $a$ is close to unity and as $N$ grows it converges to $1$.